# Get Currently Executing Class/Method Name?

Tags: apex, logging

I have seen a few different flavors of exception logging utility out there, and a common concept is to capture the class and method that were running when the exception was thrown. In the case that made me wonder this, the logger is used for more than just exceptions. It has method signatures like:

```
public static void logMessage
    (LoggingLevel loggingLevel, String className, String methodName, String message)
```

**It seems to me that we should be able to get the `className` and `methodName` parameters programatically. Can it be done? How?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

My first thought (which does work) is to `throw` and `catch` a `DmlException` (or any `Exception` type you wish), and use its stack trace string as a starting point.

```
public class StackTrace
{
    public static String getCurrentString()
    {
        try { throw new DmlException(); }
        catch (DmlException e)
        {
            return e.getStackTraceString().substringAfter('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `substringAfter('\n')`. One of the tricky aspects of this pursuit is that you add calls to the stack in any attempt to write a generic tool to parse the stack trace for you.

While the above code works, upon further inspection it seems the `Exception` constructor does the work of building the stack trace, and we don't even need to throw. The following method is more concise, works just as well, and consumes less CPU:

```
public static String getCurrrentString()
{
    return new DmlException().getStackTraceString().substringAfter('\n');
}
```

---

So now we know how to get the stack trace. That's all well and good, but we still need to parse it to get the class name and method. Here are some example values:

> Class.Demo.Subclass.doStuff: line 18, column 1
>   Class.Demo.doStuff: line 7, column 1
>   AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1

So how do we get the class and method names? Here's one approach:

```
global static String getClassName(String line)
{
    if (line.startsWith('Class.'))
        line = line.substringAfter('Class.');
    return line.substringBefore(':').substringBeforeLast('.');
}    
global static String getMethod(String line)
{
    return line.substringBefore(':').substringAfterLast('.');
}
```

And if you want convenience methods to get the currently executing class and method, they would look something like:

```
global static String getClassName()
{
    return getClassName(new DmlException().getStackTraceString().substringAfter('\n'));
}
global static String getMethod()
{
    return getMethod(new DmlException().getStackTraceString().substringAfter('\n'));
}
```

---

Back to the initial problem, how would we integrate this approach into our `Logger` class? If we try the below approach, we'll log every time that we're in the `Logger.smartLog` method!

```
public static void smartLog(LoggingLevel level)
{
    logMessage(level, StackTrace.getClassName(), StackTrace.getMethod());
}
```

The most efficient and straightforward approach would be to simply not add that call to the stack.

```
public static void smartLog(LoggingLevel level)
{
    String trace = new DmlException().getStackTraceString().substringAfter('\n');
    logMessage(level, StackTrace.getClassName(trace), StackTrace.getMethod(trace));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the exception constructor; also avoid messy debug log pollution with exceptions thrown that can "throw off" the debug log reader with spurious noise

Comment: If the stack trace is set in the constructor, what happens if the exception instance is passed off to another class and thrown there? Seems the trace would be way off. Probably doesn't matter for your purposes.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't reuse these exceptions for other purposes.

Comment: Curiously, custom exceptions don't work in the expression `return new MyException().getStackTraceString().substringAfter('\n');`  -- no stacktrace is returned. I had to use `DmlException` or `StringException` or presumably any OOTB exception.

Comment: Right, only standard exceptions. I wonder why? Maybe you can overwrite that method?

Comment: @cropredy  IMO, we don't need stacktrace in case of custom exception, we can pass messages directly(which will helps us to process the exception(using getMessage).

Comment: or to make code more generic, we can override the same with override keyword(one good thing is that we can use getMessage() to return value from getStackTraceString() method.

Comment: @ysr I think you missed his point entirely. *If* you want to parse stack trace to determine calling context, *then* custom exceptions will not work.

Comment: I am referring to the use of override (and the freedom of passing the message. Why I'll be needing code to do processing to get className, when I can directly pass the same information[in string] while throwing the exception. ). Please correct me,if I am overlooking something.

Comment: Gotcha. He's telling us-we can't get stack trace in case of custom exceptions. Sorry, my bad.