# How to get running class and method names programmatically?

Tags: apex, debugging, regular-expressions, stacktrace

There is a logger class in my org that accepts class name and method name as parameters. So often, you will see code of roughly the following form:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void myMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        catch (SomeException e)
        {
            new Logger(e, 'MyClass', 'myMethod').handle();
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to get these values programmatically instead of forcing the developer to pass them in?** It would be a bonus to get the line and column numbers as well.

```
public class Logger
{
    public final String className, methodName;
    public final Integer line, column
    public Logger()
    {
        // determine class and method names of the calling context
        // optionally determine line and column numbers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a fun fact to get the ball rolling: the **constructor** for any `Exception` class will generate the current stack trace (no need to throw). So you can, for instance, get the stack trace in your logger constructor:

```
final String firstLine;
public Logger()
{
    String stackTrace = new DmlException()
        .getStackTraceString().substringAfter('\n');

    // being in the constructor adds one line at the top of the stack
    // ignore the first line to get the stack trace of the calling context

    firstLine = stackTrace.substringBefore('\n');
}
```

That provides a good basis to start working the problem, but we still need to understand what sort of input/output combos we might need to support. To that end, I spun up a quick class with some basic types of calling context (first line of stack trace in comments):

```
public class Demo
{
    public Logger l;
    public Demo()
    { // top-level constructor
        l = new Logger(); //Class.Demo.<init>: line 6, column 1
    }
    public static Logger foo()
    { // top-level method
        return new Logger(); //Class.Demo.foo: line 10, column 1
    }
    public class Sub
    {
        Logger l;
        public Sub()
        { // inner-class constructor
            l = new Logger(); //Class.Demo.Sub.<init>: line 17, column 1
        }
        public Logger bar()
        { // inner-class method
            return new Logger(); //Class.Demo.Sub.bar: line 21, column 1
        }
    }
    public static String someProperty
    {
        get
        { // property getter
            system.debug(new Logger()); //Class.Demo.__sfdc_someProperty: line 28, column 1
            return someProperty;
        }
        set
        { // property setter
            system.debug(new Logger()); //Class.Demo.__sfdc_someProperty: line 33, column 1
            someProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It's also a bit different from anonymous scripts:

```
Logger l = new Logger(); //AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1
Logger foo()
{ // anonymous method
    return new Logger(); //AnonymousBlock: line 4, column 1
}
class Anon
{
    Logger l;
    Anon()
    { // anonymous class constructor
        l = new Logger(); //Class.Anon.<init>: line 10, column 1
    }
    Logger bar()
    { // anonymous class method
        return new Logger(); //Class.Anon.bar: line 15, column 1
    }
}
```

Okay, so a Regular Expression seems like the way to go. Let's [try one out](https://regex101.com/r/7xJpmX/1):

> **Explanation**
>   `/
>   ^(?:class\.)?([^.]+)\.?([^\.\:]+)?[\.\:]?([^\.\:]*): line (\d+), column (\d+)$
>   / gim`
>
> - `^` asserts position at start of a line
> - Non-capturing group `(?:class\.)?`
>
>   - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>   - `class` matches the characters `class` literally (case insensitive)
>   - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)
> - **1st Capturing Group** `([^.]+)`
>
>   - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^.]+`
>
>     - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>     - `.` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)
> - `\.?` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)
>
>   - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - **2nd Capturing Group** `([^\.\:]+)?`
>
>   - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>   - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\.\:]+`
>
>     - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>     - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)
>     - `\:` matches the character `:` literally (case insensitive)
> - Match a single character present in the list below [.:]?
>
>   - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
>     - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)
>     - `\:` matches the character `:` literally (case insensitive)
> - **3rd Capturing Group** `([^\.\:]*)`
>
>   - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\.\:]*`
>
>     - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>     - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)
>     - `\:` matches the character `:` literally (case insensitive)
> - `: line`  matches the characters `: line`  literally (case insensitive)
> - **4th Capturing Group** `(\d+)`
>
>   - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
>
>     - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - `, column`  matches the characters `, column`  literally (case insensitive)
> - **5th Capturing Group** `(\d+)`
> - `$` asserts position at the end of a line

In plain english:

- The entire search is case-insensitive.
- The line may or may not start with the substring `'class.'`. Ignore this substring.
- First Capturing Group (`group(1)`)

  - If there are one or more `'.'` characters, match the remaining characters before the first `'.'` character.
  - If there is no `'.'` character, match the remaining characters before the `':'` character.
- Match the first `'.'` character if one is present. Ignore this substring.
- Second Capturing Group (`group(2)`)

  - If there is no `'.'` character, match nothing.
  - If there is one `'.'` character, match everything between it and the `':'` character.
  - If there are two `'.'` characters, match everything between the first and second `'.'` character.
- Match the second `'.'` character if one is present. Ignore this substring.
- Third Capturing Group (`group(3)`)

  - If there are fewer than two `'.'` characters, match nothing.
  - If there are two `'.'` characters, match everything between the second `'.'` character and the `':'` character.
- Match `': column '`. This substring must be present. Ignore it.
- Fourth Capturing Group (`group(4)`)

  - Match all digits. There must be at least one.
- Match `', line '`. This substring must be present. Ignore it.
- Fifth Capturing Group (`group(5)`)

  - Match all digits. There must be at least one.

With that expression figured out, here's a class implementation that works for me in the scenarios I have tested:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static Matcher generateMatcher(String firstLine)
    {
        return Pattern.compile(
            '(?i)^(?:class\\.)?([^.]+)\\.?([^\\.\\:]+)?[\\.\\:]?([^\\.\\:]*): line (\\d+), column (\\d+)$'
        ).matcher(firstLine);
    }

    public final String className, methodName;
    public final Integer line, column;
    public Logger()
    {
        Matcher m = generateMatcher(
            new DmlException()
                .getStackTraceString()
                .substringAfter('\n')
                .substringBefore('\n')
        );
        if (m.find())
        {
            if (String.isBlank(m.group(3)))
            {
                className = m.group(1);
                methodName = prettifyMethodName(m.group(2));
            }
            else
            {
                className = m.group(1) + '.' + m.group(2);
                methodName = prettifyMethodName(m.group(3));
            }
            line = Integer.valueOf(m.group(4));
            column = Integer.valueOf(m.group(5));
        }
    }
    String prettifyMethodName(String name)
    {
        return (name == null) ? null :
            name.replace('<init>', '(constructor) ')
                .replace('__sfdc_', '(getter/setter) ');
    }
}
```

The prettification is obviously an unnecessary step. For instance, with it removed, I get the following yields:

```
public class Demo
{
    public Logger l;
    public Demo()
    { // top-level class constructor
        l = new Logger(); // Logger:[className=Demo, column=1, line=6, methodName=<init>]
    }
    public static Logger foo()
    { // top-level class method
        return new Logger(); // Logger:[className=Demo, column=1, line=10, methodName=foo]
    }
    public class Sub
    {
        public Logger l;
        public Sub()
        { // inner class constructor
            l = new Logger(); // Logger:[className=Demo.Sub, column=1, line=17, methodName=<init>]
        }
        public Logger bar()
        { // inner class method
            return new Logger(); // Logger:[className=Demo.Sub, column=1, line=21, methodName=bar]
        }
    }
    public static String someProperty
    {
        get
        { // property getter
            system.debug(new Logger()); // Logger:[className=Demo, column=1, line=33, methodName=__sfdc_someProperty]
            return someProperty;
        }
        set
        { // property setter
            system.debug(new Logger()); // Logger:[className=Demo, column=1, line=28, methodName=__sfdc_someProperty]
            someProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the design I came up with a few years ago. The only caveat is that exceptions are "expensive" (~50ms per throw/catch), so this method has to be used relatively sparingly.

Comment: @sfdcfox Reread the first sentence. :) They grab the stack trace at *construction* time, not throw time.

Comment: Hmm. Kind of surprised that works. Looks like I need to update my library :D

Comment: Epic stuff. I will be bookmarking this.

Comment: Very nice, Adrian. I wanted to do exactly the same today. I owe you one. Could I suggest to add a reference to this answer over here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153835/get-currently-executing-class-method-name

Comment: Ah, hmm, didn't realize I posted a duplicate of my own question. Oops.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - in your code you create a member variable for  the logger in each class where you want to use the logger. Is there a reason you chose that design over putting it in a static method in the logging class? (like Logger.add() )?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana Not sure what you're getting at, but I'm happy to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105197/class-method-logger) about it.